# Currying a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

There is a mapping which I will call the "currying operator" $\hat\square:Z^{X\times Y}\to(Z^Y)^X$ which maps $f:X\times Y\to Z$ to $\hat f:X\to Z^Y$ defined as $x\mapsto y\mapsto f(x,y)$, or equivalently $\hat f(x)(y)=f(x,y)$. This mapping $f\mapsto\hat f$ is a bijection, and sufficiently "natural" that I expect it to be able to transport topological structure on the sets, in the sense of category theory.

So suppose that $X,Y,Z$ are topological spaces, and topologize $X\times Y$ with the product topology. What topology do I put on $Z^Y$ (this being the set of *continuous* functions $Y\to Z$) to ensure that $f$ is continuous iff $\hat f$ is continuous? My guess is the compact-open topology, since I've heard it called the "natural" topology for a function space, but does anyone have a reference for the proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't (in full generality) : $\mathsf{Top}$ is not cartesian closed. See the [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces) for more detail.

Comment: What extra assumptions do you need to make it true?

Comment: (From the nLab page I guess the answer to my question would be that $Y$ is core-compact.) In general spaces, which inclusion is continuous (or are they both discontinuous)? I.e. do we have $f$ continuous $\implies\hat f$ continuous in general, even if it is not bidirectonal?

Comment: Also, the nLab page, although a good exposition, frustratingly contains no proofs, and there isn't too much other good coverage of this topic on the net. Do you know a textbook or similar that goes through these results?

Comment: It's in Kelley and also Munkres – look up "compact open topology".

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Have a look at [CGWH](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fneil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk%2Fcourses%2Fhomotopy%2Fcgwh.pdf&ei=3SH-VNLlE4HuPNS0gKAI&usg=AFQjCNEJ8T1hrVAKbVqtvl0_t6BhVZEpkQ&sig2=LfnfHmP_67p-BBrP3X-TLw&bvm=bv.87611401,d.ZWU), which deals with the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces (or as others call them *weak Hausdorff k-spaces*), and it provides detailed proofs that this category is Cartesian closed.

Comment: One more reference for different options of cartesian closed subcategories of Top is http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864104000550 .

Answer (score 6):

The excellent text [Topology and Groupoids](http://www.amazon.ca/Topology-Groupoids-Ronald-Brown/dp/1419627228/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1425936983&sr=8-1&keywords=brown+topology) by Ronald Brown discusses this extensively in chapter 5.9 and contains complete proofs. The category of topological spaces is not Cartesian closed, so in general you don't have an exponential object for any pair of topological spaces. However, the category of [compactly generated spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) (k-spaces) has the desired property, and contains many spaces of interest such as first countable spaces, locally compact spaces, metrizable spaces, manifolds, CW complexes, etc.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Note that the Wiki article gives a different definition than Brown's book in that it does not assume that the maps whose final topology the space in question has are Hausdorff.

Comment: @StefanHamcke, user59001: Do either of you know if locally compact Hausdorff spaces are cartesian closed? I know that these are contained in the compactly generated Hausdorff spaces, but it might be that the exponential of two LCH spaces is CGH but not LCH.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: The exponential of two locally compact spaces need not be locally compact.